# Moving elements across child nodes

Tags: java, xml, xslt

I have multiple child nodes under topics. I need to move elements from one of the child [as per condition] to another child node [as per condition].

My input xml looks as below. I want to iterate through all topics and copy the class element from title="wildlife" to title="books".

```
   <node-A>
    <logs>abc</logs>
    <topics>
        <topic>
            <topic-header>
                <title>wildlife</title>
            </topic-header>
            <basis>
                <variant>
                    <property>
                        <class code="books" description="books" sourceSystem="">books
                        </class>
                    </property>
                </variant>
            </basis>
        </topic>
        <topic>
            <topic-header>
                <title>library</title>
            </topic-header>
            <basis>
                <variant>
                    <property>
                        <x></x>
                        <y></y>
                        <z></z>
                    </property>
                </variant>
            </basis>
        </topic>
    </topics>
</node-A>
```

My output XML should look like as below:

```
    <node-A>
    <logs>abc</logs>
    <topics>
        <topic>
            <topic-header>
                <title>wildlife</title>
            </topic-header>
            <basis>
                <variant>
                    <property>
                        <class code="books" description="books" sourceSystem="">books
                        </class>
                    </property>
                </variant>
            </basis>
        </topic>
        <topic>
            <topic-header>
                <title>library</title>
            </topic-header>
            <basis>
                <variant>
                    <property>
                        <x></x>
                        <y></y>
                        <z></z>
<class code="books" description="books" sourceSystem="">books
                        </class>
                    </property>
                </variant>
            </basis>
        </topic>
    </topics>
</node-A>
```

Comment: With xslt? What did you try? It looks like the problem is not well defined. What if there are multiple `topic`s with the class element? Which one should be used?

Comment: We need to use XSLT. I have no idea what to try here. Please give some hints.

Comment: Every topic will have the class element but I need to pick from topic/topic-header/title="wildlife" and paste it in child node with "books" title.

Comment: I would select the class element into a variable. https://www.xmltutorial.info/xslt/xslvariable/ and then use it in a template. I'm not sure if there's another way.

Comment: I tried with variable but in actual I have more than 50 elements to be migrated [just like code], so I will end up creating 50 variables. My solution was discarded. Any idea on how to change the mode when I find "books".

Answer (score 0):

**You can try this:**

```
    <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
version="2.0">
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="property[not(class)]">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="//property/class"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: It copies class element from all topic nodes. I need to copy from wildlife to library only. can we add some conditional checks here.

Comment: Try `<xsl:apply-templates select="//topic[topic-header/title='wildlife']/basis/variant/property/class"/>`